# IIS Timeout automatically getting reset

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a website running on IIS 7.5.7600

We set the Session State.Time Out (In Minutes) to 900
It is getting reset to 20.

We think we have narrowed it to Sunday between noon and midnight.

**Is there anything that will automatically reset this setting.**

Our HW group is aware and engaged, but they have no ideas.

I do understand 900 is a long timeout. Unless there is some boundary at which IIS acts differently, the length of the timeout is not open to change. If it is too large, for a technical reason, Id appreciate a link that I can take to the decision maker.

Also, this is not an application pool issue. The value is honored... up until the point it gets reset.

Comment: There was a power outage this morning at the client and the setting was put back at 20 minutes. I checked it yesterday and it was fine.  Hmm, I looked, cant find a 'please reset my preferences to whatever you feel like' check box.

Comment: What are you using for Sessions?, StateServer?, In Proc?, checked your web config file?. Is anyone re-deploying the site to iis ? as this can carry settings across.

Comment: I am deploying changes about twice a week. This was the first suspect. This is not the cause.
we are using in process sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This stopped getting reset. 
I do not have a great answer.

I ruled out me publishing application updates
I ruled out the general app pool issues. 
I ruled out reboots/updates

Something was running and causing this. It wasnt gremlins.

Possibly just raising the issue to the larger organization of those involved caused either someone to change their behavior, or to alter some process. Its a good group of guys. I don't think anyone was being less than above board.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had similar issue, until I realized that there are 3 places session state can be set:

1. Server Level
2. Default website
3. And the application itself

Make sure that you don't miss any!